# 45Gb used out of 70Gb but only about 500Mb left according to df. How to troubleshoot the reason?

Tags: linux, filesystems, fedora, disk-space, ext4

I’ve an ext4 filesystem which is stored as a file inside another fileystem *(not a block device)*.

On this system, I have 2 Berkley databases with the first being 25Gb large and the second being 20Gb large (both consisting of many small files) so I’m sure about the theoretical space being used (I don’t know  however how to check for the space actually used on disk).

**So this represent a 36% of disk space being declared as used compared to theoretical free disk space which is quite high for a filesystem using extents allocations from the start.**

- I just created the filesystem and the problem did occur when attempting to fill it so it was never unmounted (even incorrectly) before, but anyway I tried to unmount the filesystem and `fsck` both the host filesystem and the ext4 filesystem but it found nothing.
- I tried to fill the filesystem with `dd if=/dev/zero of=wipe` using the root user and indeed it can only write about 500Mb before running out of disk space.

How to troubleshoot the reason and possibly fix it?

Comment: What is your method to tell the space being used? Please [edit] the question and post the exact command (if it's a CLI command) and its output. Is it `du`? What if you use `du -ks /the/mountpoint`? What is the output of `df -k /the/mountpoint`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I don’t think it’s relevant as I written that additionally a `dd` test prove that’s it indeed the space being available knowing that `dd`doesn’t rely on the space being reported as available by the system.

Comment: Fair enough. I won't force you to get my (or anyone else's) help. It's your choice.